# VBScript to execute a batch file on a remote server

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, automation, remote-server, jscript

Friends please help me with a VBscript code or a batch script or any possible way that executes a batch file on remote desktop.

I tried a lot but couldn't succeed.

**Note: psexec or any other external tools are not provided.**

Comment: WMI; http://4sysops.com/archives/three-ways-to-run-remote-windows-commands/#method-2-use-wmi-to-run-remote-commands

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a use of a batch file with [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). Download psexec, copy/paste this into a batch file and edit the variables where needed. I use a similar process on several nightly Control-M jobs.

```
@ECHO OFF

REM ***** Set path to PSEXEC.exe *****
SET PSEXEC="H:\Utilities\PsTools\psexec.exe"

REM ***** Set path to batch file on remote server (unc paths work)
SET BATCHFILE="C:\path\to\batch.bat"

REM ***** Set server to execute batch on
SET REMOTESERVER="\\testserver"

REM ***** PRODUCTION SERVERS *****

ECHO Executing %BATCHFILE% on %REMOTESERVER%
%PSEXEC% %REMOTESERVER% %BATCHFILE%
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this solution by scheduling the batch files using windows scheduler and i triggered the windows scheduler to run the batch file using the below code

```
 string job = @"""\JobLocation\JobName""";
            string server = @"XXXXXXXXXXX";
            string user = @"Domian\XXXXXX";
            string pwd = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            string line = @" /run /tn " + job + " /s " + server + " /u " + user + "  /p " + pwd;

            var process = new Process();
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\schtasks.exe",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                Arguments = line,
                //WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            };
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            string errors = process.StandardError.ReadLine();
```